¿Como puedo arreglar esto? Warning: Errors during XML parse
Estoy instalando flutter en Android Studio, he seguido la documentación pero a la hora de aceptar las licencias tenía que correr en el cmd
C:> flutter doctor --android-licenses
Y al finalizar lo que me debía dar era esto
[========================================] 100% Computing updates...  
All SDK package licenses accepted. 
Pero en realidad me dio esto:
Warning: Errors during XML parse: 
Warning: Additionally, the fallback loader failed to parse the XML.
[=======================================] 100% Computing updates... 
All SDK package licenses accepted. 
¿Alguien sabe como arreglarlo? o si no hay problema con que lo deje así?
Estuve buscando en varias páginas pero no encontré una solución al problema :(

android studio es simplemente "maravilloso" para instalar cualquier cosa, prueba a reinciar el pc y que no haya ningún proceso que puedo pueda estar utilizando algun archivo

Muy importante saber que versión de Android Studio y sistema operativo usas? Usas Chromebook ?

Hola, gracias por responder. Estoy usando Android studio hedgehog y ocupo Windows. Mi laptop es una ASUS TUF
